Change CSS Only for WooCommerce New Order Notification sent to Admins
I want to change the header table design on new order notifications only for my admins. Customer emails should be unaffected. The code I have is below but it does not seem to want to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_styles', 'add_css_to_new_order_email', 9999, 2 );

function add_css_to_new_order_email( $css, $email ) { 
   if ( $email->id == 'new_order' && $email->recipient == 'admin' ) {
      $css .= '
         #header_wrapper { background-color: #000!important; }
         h1 { color: #000!important; }
      ';
   }
   return $css;
}


Have you verified that the conditions are actually fulfilled? What happens when you add the CSS without any conditions?

In your IF statement, $email->recipient == 'admin' will always be false as you need to define the real admin email.
As New Order email notification is always sent to the admins only (but not to the customer), you don't need $email->recipient == 'admin' in your IF statement.
Try the following:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_styles', 'add_css_to_new_order_email', 20, 2 );
function add_css_to_new_order_email( $css, $email ) { 
    if ($email->id === 'new_order') {
        $css .= ' #header_wrapper { background-color: #000 !important; } 
        h1 { color: #000 !important; }';
    } 
    return $css;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Related:

Target a specific email notification with the email id in WooCommerce
Add order item price per kilo in WooCommerce New Order notification
Display the Remaining Stock Quantity for each order item only in WooCommerce new order email notification


Thanks as always @LoictTheAztec. I seem to have got really muddled with the new order (admin) and order received email that is sent to customer. If the new order is only for admins then what is the ID for the customer facing email? I think I’ve been assuming that the new_order  targets both as the IDs I’ve found listed are: new_order
customer_on_hold_order
customer_processing_order
customer_completed_order
customer_refunded_order
customer_partially_refunded_order
cancelled_order
failed_order
customer_reset_password
customer_invoice
customer_new_account
customer_note

Yep had seen that and referred to it. I'm guessing customer_processing_order is the first email that is sent to the customer. Also yes, aware of what to do. I always mark my answers and upvote, apologies if I've missed anything in the past. Just hadn't got a chance to get to my computer to test the code :) Thank you again!

@Acephalia For the first email sent to the customer, It depends on the payment method used for the order, so the email ID can be customer_on_hold_order or customer_processing_order or even customer_completed_order in some cases.

Yes that makes total sense now. I’ve been real daft about it >.< Appreciate you!
